# PHP Catchable fatal error INI handling class

Tags: php, ini

I my project I'm using [this](http://codepad.org/t71yrLvb) class to handle ini files.
I've developed all the project using Windows EasyPHP but when I put it in my Linux webserver, I always get this error in the log files (either using Lighttpd or Cherokee, the error is the same)

> [12/11/2013 15:10:29.697] (error) handler_fcgi.c:115 - PHP Warning:
>       parse_ini_file(Conf\confFile.ini): failed to open stream: No such file or
>       directory in /var/www/ini.class.php on line 27 PHP Catchable fatal error:
>       Argument 1 passed to Config::__construct() must be of the type array,
>       boolean given, called in /var/www/ini.class.php on line 27 and defined in
>       /var/www/ini.class.php on line 15

Comment: provide your own relevant code

Comment: Linux uses a forward slash for a directory separator `/` whereas windows uses a backwards slash `\`. PHP has a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) to help you out.

Comment: well the error states that it cannot find the file, which causes the later errors, just going on something you said (developed on windows and moved to linux) check that you capitalisation is correct in your scripts linux really cares if its function Bla() or function bla()

Comment: I've used PHP's DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR (thanks Mike) instead of backslashes and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your PHP process cannot access the file.

Normally this is either because the PHP process isn't running from where you think it is (and so the path is wrong).  Try echoing 'getcwd()' and ssee if it returns when you expect.

Or, the path is right, but your PHP process doesn't have the required permissions to access the file.